# PagedList MVC to get data from db based on pagesize

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

i added PagedList in my project, i have a search view, which basically calls a function to get values from database, my Pagedlist is working fine, but i am not sure if this gets whole data from database or only based on pageSize. For example i have total 30 records, and i added pagesize as 10, so view will show 10 records at a time and 3 pages. Now this PagedList get all 30 values, or only get 10 first time, then if user click on page 2 it gets next 10 records.

Because lets say i have thousand records, so i dont want system to load all of them, i just want to load it according to pagesize , and when user click on second page it gets next records, hope my point is clear, below is my code:

View:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<BackendIntegration.Models.VendorAllTransactions>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@if (Model != null)
{
<hr />
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <table class="table">
        <tr class="bg-primary">
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayName("Date")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayName("Type")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayName("Amount")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayName("User Name")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayName("Vendor Name")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayName("POS ID")
            </th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var trans in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => trans.Date)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => trans.TypeDesc)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => trans.Amount)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => trans.UserName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => trans.VendorName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => trans.POS_ID)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
    <br />
    <div id='Paging' style="text-align: center">
        Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber)
        of @Model.PageCount

        @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("VendorAllTransactions", new { page }))
    </div>  
</div>
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult VendorAllTransactions(VendorAllTransactionView vw, int? page)
        {
            int pageSize = 10;
            int pageIndex = 1;
            pageIndex = page.HasValue ? Convert.ToInt32(page) : 1;

            IPagedList<VendorAllTransactions> model = null;

            try
            {
                model = sales.VendorAllTransactions(vw).ToPagedList(pageIndex, pageSize);
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", exp.Message);
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

`sales.VendorAllTransactions(vw)` this call a fucntion with query, which will return records. But this clearly returning all the records. Is Pagedlist get only required number of rows(pagesize) or it gets everything.???

Please advise.
Thanks

Comment: as it was explained in the library documentation  it will only get the current page you're requsting. => https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList#what-is-this

Comment: You can enable EF database log so you can see the generated query.

Comment: Internally it use `.Skip()` and `.Take()` to get only the 10 records you requested

Comment: @CodeNotFound if i add `Database.Log = sql => Debug.Write(sql);` this will give me query run , but how can i get the returned rows count. to validate if it is getting 10(pagesize) rows or not. thanks